# Double Iterator Loop

Tags: java, list, iterator, linked-list

So I have this loop in my code that needs two separately working Iterators. However, when it tries to use rbIterator.next(), java throws a ConcurrentModificationException. How do I stop that from happening? 
Thanks

```
Iterator<Road> raIterator = roads.listIterator(0); //I also tried .iterator(), with no avail
while(raIterator.hasNext()){
    Road ra = raIterator.next();
    Iterator<Road> rbIterator = roads.listIterator(0);
    while(rbIterator.hasNext()){
        Road rb = rbIterator.next();
        //snipped code that adds a road to the list
        roads.add(xyz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add items to most standard implementations of `List` while iterating over them, unless you create an implementation that allows it!

`ArrayList` does not, however, see [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Nor do most* (perhaps all) of the Java Collections Frameworks `List` implementations.

A solution would be to create a new list, `temp`, before iterating, add elements to `temp` while you iterate, and then add all of the elements in `temp` to the first.

Edit: used `addAll(temp)`, thanks @Michael Easter

```
List<Road> temp = new ArrayList<Road>();

for(Road ra : roads){
    for (Road rb : roads){
        temp.add(xyz);
    }
}

roads.addAll(temp);
```

Comment: suggested edit is simply "roads.addAll(temp);" instead of the 2nd loop

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `ListIterator<E>` instead, you will be able to add. The reason you are getting the exception is b/c of this(from the javadocs):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

You cannot modify the list itself directly, but through the iterator, you may. The base `Iterator<E>` class does not have an add method, but `ListIterator<E>` does, which is what you are getting when you call the `obj.listIterator()` anywqay.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem before. It is because you are trying to iterate over the same thing (roads) twice. This is dangerous, because if one iterator modifies roads, then the other iterator is thrown into an unknown/unreliable state.

If you could manage to use a for loop that would solve this problem, since it seems to fulfil the needs. That would depend on the type of roads (which you have not included) though.

Comment: The issue isn't related to the double iteration at all, only to the call to add().

Comment: It is related to iteration. When you call add, you have modified the list that is being iterated over, so the same thing is being modified concurrently, hence the exception.

Comment: Iterating *twice* has nothing to do with it.

Comment: A for loop would cause problems unless it was done properly (using a local variable to serve as the condition for the inner loop). Iterating twice is fine as long as the collections aren't modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can't using an Iterator. However, you can use direct access via List's [get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method.

This code does what you want (and compiles and runs OK):

```
for (int i = 0; i < roads.size(); i++) {
    Road ra = roads.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < roads.size(); j++) {
        Road rb = roads.get(i);
        //snipped code that adds a road to the list
        roads.add(xyz);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem using this method is that you run the risk (read: you will) use any new roads each time you hit the inner loop, which is *most likely* not desired. A way around this would be to set a local variable equal to `roads.size()` before you begin the first loop and use it for the inner loop's constraint.